# How to prevent Rails parallel tests and Sidekiq from calling Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, debouncing, parallel-testing, rspec-sidekiq

I have a Rails application that is using Sidekiq for asynchronous jobs.
I setup parallel testing to speed up my testing pipeline.  This is working great but I have one major problem:  Redis is bottlenecking with Sidekiq jobs trying to enqueue work there.

I keep seeing these errors:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError:
Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I am running some old versions of gems and also using Sidekiq debounce (Not sure if this is the reason)

`sidekiq (5.2.1)`
`sidekiq-debounce (1.1.0)`
`rspec-sidekiq (3.0.3)`

I was under the impression that rspec-sidekiq would be able to either stub the calls to Redis by using either: `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` or `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!` to run the jobs inline or push them to an array respectively.
However neither of these options are working.  What am I missing?

I tried setting up the test environment to fake or inline the jobs like:

```
require "sidekiq/testing"

Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

OR

```
require "sidekiq/testing"

Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

Then I even checked in some of the tests to make sure this was being set by:

```
puts "SIDEKIQ MODE ENABLED: #{Sidekiq::Testing.enabled?}"
puts "SIDEKIQ MODE FAKE: #{Sidekiq::Testing.fake?}"
puts "SIDEKIQ MODE INLINE: #{Sidekiq::Testing.inline?}"
puts "SIDEKIQ MODE DISABLED: #{Sidekiq::Testing.disabled?}"
```

and it returned what I expected but I still got the Redis connections refused.

I also tried wrapping the individual parts in blocks like:

```
Sidekiq::Testing.fake! do
 # some code
end
```

Comment: I think I figured out the problem.  The sidekiq-debounce gem was interferring.  So I changed some settings in my Sidekiq initializer to not enable the middleware for debounce.

Comment: Please share details as an answer (answering your own question is welcome here!), so you can help others <3 Don't forget to mention what settings you have changes, and why.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the advice :) I'm new to answering and even posting on Stackoverflow so I wasn't sure what I should/shouldn't do.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. If that solves you problem - hit also accept (a bit checkmark under the votes in your answer) to help people find the solution. Welcome aboard!

Comment: Ah thanks!  I can only accept in 2 days it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I figured out what was wrong or what to change.
We were using Sidekiq along with [Sidekiq-debounce](https://github.com/hummingbird-me/sidekiq-debounce)
I think this was actually intercepting the basic Sidekiq async calls so even though I set them to `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!` or `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!`, this did not affect jobs being called using `SomeWorker.perform_in()`

I ended disabling the debounce middleware for the test environment in our `sidekiq.rb` initializer:

```html
unless Rails.env.test?
  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.client_middleware do |chain|
      chain.add Sidekiq::Debounce
    end
  end
end

if Rails.env.test?
  require 'sidekiq/testing'
  Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
end
```

Ran the pipeline again and no longer saw the Redis connection problems.